# How to prevent whitespaces in JQuery and allow user to enter name

Tags: jquery, html

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var form = $("#contact_form");
    var FName = $("#fname"); //Creates Variables from forms 
    var FNameInfo = $("#fnameInfo");
    var Tele = $("#tele"); 
    var TeleInfo = $("#teleInfo"); 
    var Address = $("#address");
    var AddressInfo = $("#addInfo"); 
    var Email = $("#email");
    var EmailInfo = $("#EmailInfo"); 
    var regexp = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+[a-zA-Z0-9.]+.[a-z]{2,4}$/; //ragex code 

    FName.blur(validateFName);  //blur is a method which attaches a functiom to run when an event occurs
    Email.blur(validateEmail); 
    Tele.blur(validateTele);
    Address.blur(validateAddress);

    form.submit (  
        if (validateFName()& validateTele() & validateEmail() & validateAddress() ){ //If it passes all of these then return true 
            return true;    
    }else  {
                return false;        
              }
        }); 

        function validateFName () {   //Creates function for Name Validation+

         var str = $("#fname").val();

        if ( str < 5 ||  str.indexOf(" ") !== -1 ) {        //If name is length is less than 5 and no white spaces 

                FName.addClass("error");  //Display error 
                FNameInfo.text("Please Enter Correct Name"); //Changes span name 
                FNameInfo.addClass("error");  //Same error 
                FNameInfo.removeClass("Valid");   

                return false; 

        }         
       else  {
                FName.removeClass("error");   //remove error class 
                FNameInfo.addClass("Valid") 
                FNameInfo.text("Thanks Buddy" );  //When user enters correct code this text will appear 
                FNameInfo.removeClass("error"); 
                return true; 
       }          
   }           
});

</script> 
    <div> 
          <label for ="name">Full Name </label>
          <input id = "fname" name = "fname" type = "text"/> 
          <span id = "fnameInfo" > Whats your full name?</span>
    </div>
```

Ok in here I want the user to enter the correct full name. Its a validation testing so I need to validate white spaces, however it does work to a certain extent for example if user enters space multiple time and then adds a '.' full stop it does display error but when I erase that and enter correct full name it still displays error only way to get the error corrected is by entering something stupid like 'ppppppp' or '........' otherwise it still displays error any idea how I can make the error go away when I enter correct name?

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean, if you want to prevent spaces things like `"pppppp"` would work. If I entered my full name `"Spencer Wieczorek"`, there is a space between the words, which would fail because your code prevents any spaces.

Comment: I see, so is there a way where I can enter the full name with spacing in the middle without a big change to code or would I need to completly change the code infrastructure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your validation of names you would need to have the value be in the format of: `first [middle] last [etc]* ...` or in general just words followed by spaces with a word on the end. In this case you will want to use a Regular Expression to look for that pattern. So you would use:

```
/^[a-zA-Z]+( [a-zA-Z]+)+$/
```

If you would like to limit this to say only 3 words then you can do you could make that into `/^[a-zA-Z]+( [a-zA-Z]+){1,2}$/`. So in your code say `str` is the fullname you would do:

```
// If the string is in the proper format return true, false otherwise.
if(/^[a-zA-Z]+( [a-zA-Z]+)+$/.test(str)) {
    ...
    return true;
} else {
    ...
    return false;
}
```

Note this does not allow spaces after the user enters their name, so for example:  `"Spencer Wieczorek "` would be false.